# ¿Como obtener los elementos del item listview del boton seleccionado Android Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.android

vengo a consultarle un problema que no puedo solucionar, tengo un listview con items en el cual cada ítem tiene los distintos textview que muestra la información y ademas tiene un boton en el cual cuando lo presiono, necesito obtener el codigo del reclamo de ese ítem que le pertenece al botón presionado.
El listview lo lleno con un adaptador, que es el siguiente:

```
  public class ClsLista : BaseAdapter<clsConsultarReclamo>
{
    private readonly IList<clsConsultarReclamo> _items;
    private readonly Context _context;
    private string _ValorRecSelecc;

    public ClsLista(Context context, IList<clsConsultarReclamo> items)
    {
        _items = items;
        _context = context;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = _items[position];
        var view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
        {
            var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(_context);
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listViewItem, parent, false);
            view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDetalleReclamo).Click += ClsLista_Click;
            //_ValorRecSelecc = _items[position].rec_IDReclamo;
        }
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvNumeroReclamo).Text = "Codigo Reclamo: ";
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvCodigoReclamo).Text = item.rec_IDReclamo;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView4tr).Text = item.tipRec_nombre;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3as).Text = item.arServ_nombre;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView7e).Text = item.estRec_nombre;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2fa).Text = item.rec_fechaAlta;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView6b).Text = item.bar_nombre;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5d).Text = item.rec_direccion;

        _ValorRecSelecc = _items[position].rec_IDReclamo;

        return view;
    }

    private void ClsLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent secondActivityDetalleReclamo = new Intent(_context, typeof(ActivityDetalleReclamo));
            secondActivityDetalleReclamo.PutExtra("codrec", _ValorRecSelecc);
            _context.StartActivity(secondActivityDetalleReclamo);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public override clsConsultarReclamo this[int position]
    {
        get { return _items[position]; }
    }

}
```

como veran alli ya tengo el evento del boton.

y yo intento capturar el valor del codigo del reclamo mediante la siguiente linea:

```
_ValorRecSelecc = _items[position].rec_IDReclamo;
```

Aclaracion, el codigo del reclamo es el rec_idReclamo

y Aquí le paso una foto de la pantalla:

[image]

Comment: sugerencia: coloca letra negrita a "los labels", tendrá mejor presentación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es no asignarle el valor a la propiedad, ya que cuando hagas click va a tener guardado el ultimo dato.

Te recomiendo que hagas algo similar al siguiente código, en el cual se ve que al método que se ejecuta en el delegate se le pasa el id del item correcto.

En lugar de esto

```
view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDetalleReclamo).Click += ClsLista_Click;
```

Pondría esto

```
var btnDetalleReclamo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDetalleReclamo);

if(!btnDetalleReclamo.HasOnClickListeners()){ // Con esto evitas de asignarle mas de una vez un listener
    btnDetalleReclamo.Click += delegate{

        ClsLista_Click(item.rec_IDReclamo); // Acá le pasarias el/los datos que necesites.

    };
}
```

y este seria el metodo modificado

```
private void ClsLista_Click(int idReclamo)
{
    try
    {
        Intent secondActivityDetalleReclamo = new Intent(_context, typeof(ActivityDetalleReclamo));
        secondActivityDetalleReclamo.PutExtra("codrec", idReclamo);
        _context.StartActivity(secondActivityDetalleReclamo);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Adrian, muchísimas gracias era justo lo que quería y no podía hacerlo funcionar de ninguna manera. Me ayudo muchísimo.